# python list, working with multiple elements

Tags: python, list

a is a list filled dynamically with values being received in no specific order.  So, if the next value received was (ID2,13), how could I remove the (ID2,10) based on the fact that ID2 was the next value received?  Because I don't know the order in which the list is being populated, I won't know the index.

Also, how would I know the count of a specfic ID?
I have tried `a.count(ID1)` but because of the second element, it fails to find any.

`a = [(ID1,10),(ID2,10),(ID1,12),(ID2,15)]`
My current usage:

```
while True:
    'Receive ID information in format (IDx,Value)'
     ID_info = (ID2,13) #For example
     if a.count(ID2) == 2: #I need to modify this line as it always returns 0
        del a[0] #This is what I need to modify to delete the correct information, as it is not always index 0
    a.append(ID_info)
else:

  a.append(ID_info)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do exactly what a dictionary does. Is there a reason you can't use that?

Comment: So you want to keep track of `IDx -> int` mappings, and there should only ever be one `ID`, and you want to regularly update it with the latest values? Sounds like a job for a `dictionary`.

Comment: I need to have multiple keys be the same, which dictionary, does not allow

Comment: Then when you get a duplicate entry, how do you know whether to remove the previous entry with the same ID or not? Does it come with that information? If you need to delete the duplicate like you said, how do you decide which duplicate to delete if there are already multiple?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question - I only want to remove the first entry with the same ID if there are already two with that ID in the list, and a third is received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the ID's are hashable, it sounds like you want to be using a dictionary.

```
a = {ID1: 10, ID2: 10}
id, val = (ID2, 13)
a[id] = val
```

With the "keep two" addition, I still think it's easier with a dictionary, though with some modifications.

EDIT: Simpler version using `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list)
a[ID1].append(10)
a[ID2].append(10)

id, val = (ID2, 13)
a[id].append(val)
if len(a[id]) > 2:
    a[id].pop(0)

def count(a, id):
    return len(a[id])
```

---

```
a = {ID1: [10], ID2: [10]}
id, val = (ID2, 13)

if id not in a.keys():
    a[id] = []

a[id].append(val)
if len(a[id]) > 2:
    a[id].pop(0)

def count(a, id):
    if id not in a.keys():
        return 0
    else:
        return len(a[id])
```

You could (and probably should) also encapsulate this behavior into a simple class inherited from `dict`.

Comment: I made a couple errors, the edit should have cleaned them up.

Comment: Instead of :
if id not in a.keys():
   a[id]=[]

I prefer to use de setdefault() method:

Comment: @user45949 Good point, though I think `collections.defaultdict` is probably the best class to use in this case. That even takes away the need for the logic in `count`.